# How to configure DNS records for Name.com and a Heroku app

Tags: heroku, dns

I'm a bit confused about how to set up the DNS records for my domain at Name.com so it can correctly point to my Heroku app.

I found DNS configuration documentation at heroku's site but I'm still confused.

I'm under the impression that I need to set up a CNAME record for all subdomains and an A record for my root domain.

Also, on the name.com website, when I try to add a CNAME there are three blank fields I need to fill out which kind of confuse me:  "Host" (where I enter '*' so it applies to all subdomains?), "Answer" (where I enter the DNS Target?), and "TTL"

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use an A-record for your root domain. Heroku is using volatile IP addresses, which means the IP you configure in your A record can stop working at any moment without notice.
See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains

On your root domain, you need to either setup an HTTP redirect to your www subdomain with your DNS provider, or use another provider which offers CNAME records for root domains.

As for the CNAME in your subdomains, yes, "Host" would be "*" to be all your subdomains.
Answer will be the endpoint provided by heroku, in the form `appname.herokudns.com.`.
TTL means how often the DNS cache should be refreshed with the clients. Using the default (or `3600` if they don't provide any) will work here.

Comment: don't you mean "appname.com.herokudns.com"? - which Nameservers should I use on Name.com? I used CNAME for Host * and for Answer "appname.com.herokudns.com" which is provided by heroku - it didn't work (after waiting 3 days) and now I'm trying with "appname.com.herokuapp.com" as Answer.

Comment: Yes. This changed. When I wrote this answer, it was `appname.herokuapp.com`. Now, it needs to be `appname.herokudns.com`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I tried that somedays ago, but it doesn't work. do I have to add Nameservers aswell? Can you give a look to my question? thx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42472895/how-to-connect-my-domain-bought-on-name-com-with-my-herokuapp

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand any of these answers :) If I want to use Heroku, do I have to drop my domain from name.com and buy it from another provider? Which one? Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

## Fully detailed steps (2)

---

### 1). Visit [Heroku apps dashboard](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps)

- Choose your app
- Click **"Settings"**
- Find text **"Add Domain"**, click button
- Add your site with www subdomain:

  - [www.yoursitename.com](http://www.yoursitename.com)
- Copy the returned **"DNS target"** value

---

### 2). Visit your [name.com account](https://www.name.com/account/domain)

- Find link text **"Manage DNS Records"** and visit link
- **"ADD RECORD"** row with the following content:

| Type: | Host: | Answer: |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CNAME | www | DNS target value from clipboard |

---

([SAUMITRA KUMAR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64573498/838517), is what helped me write this answer.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me. Start with typing this in  the Heroku CLI

```
Heroku domains: add www.youwebsitename.com --app yourherokuapp
```

This should give you a DNS target.You can obtain this from the your app settings as well on the website . Copy it and save it because we are going to need it later.Then after this run

```
heroku domains:wait for www.youwebsitename.com --app yourherokuapp
```

Then visit name.com and under your domains visit your dns records . There add CNAME entry with HOST equal to "www.yourwebsite.com" and ANSWER equal to whatever the dns target that heroku supplied you with .

Go ahead and visit your website , it'll work , if it doesn't make sure that you've used www with your website name . To fix this issue add an ANAME entry with "yourwebsite.com" as HOST and heroku dns again as target . It should reflect the changes within few hours .