# How to connect my domain bought on name.com with my herokuapp?

Tags: heroku, dns

I bought my domain on Name.com
I got my App on heroku.

On heroku added a new "custom domain":

```
Domain Name      DNS Target
mydomain.com     mydomain.com.herokudns.com
```

and on the info bubble on heroku it says:

> Supply this to your DNS provider for the destination of CNAME or ALIAS
>   records.

So I do under Name.com:

On the menu point "DNS Records":

```
Type    Host        Answer                        TTL   
CNAME   *           mydomain.com.herokudns.com    300
```

On the menu point "Nameserver":

```
ns1.name.com
ns2.name.com
ns3.name.com
ns4.name.com
```

Waited 3 days and it didn't work. So I deleted the Nameservers => didn't work.

Tried to change the "Answer" under "DNS Records" to: "myApp.herokuapp.com" ([like here mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32992445/how-to-configure-dns-records-for-name-com-and-a-heroku-app))

But I don't think this will work. So, how to make this work?

Comment: This seems like a DNS configuration issue. Could you try adding the DNS record again, and once propagation has occured, execute the following: `dig mydomain.com`?

Answer (score -1):

It needs to point to `yourapp.herokuapp.com` and you'll need to map `www` to the `Host` field.

In order to point your root domain, i.e. yourdomain.com to the Heroku app, you'll need to use a DNS service that allows CNAME flattening like CloudFlare.

See this article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain