# How to use a domain name from name.com for a Heroku app?

Tags: heroku, dns, forward, domain-name

I have an application running on `example.herokuapp.com`. No subdomains, no HTTPS, just a basic, read-only application. I also bought my domain name `example.com` from [name.com](https://www.name.com/). How do I link my domain name to the Heroku app?

I found these two questions, but I can't understand them, don't have any idea what DNS, CNAME, A records etc. are..

- [How to configure DNS records for Name.com and a Heroku app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32992445/2483127)
- [How to connect my domain bought on name.com with my herokuapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42472895/how-to-connect-my-domain-bought-on-name-com-with-my-herokuapp)

I would appreciate a dummy-friendly explanation on how to setup my domain name with my Heroku app.

From this [page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain) I understand (guess) I need to use an additional service such as DNSimple or CloudFlare, is this correct? I tried CloudFlare but there is an additional problem that my domain is already linked to 000webhost.com (which I want to remove) via name.com. Anyways, please just tell me what do I need to have in the end :) Also I prefer to use only the free plans, if possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have researched well, and the above URLs have all the steps needed. For name.com issue, see https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205195708-Step-3-Change-your-domain-name-servers-to-Cloudflare

Comment: See also https://www.name.com/support/articles/115010493967-Adding-an-ANAME-Alias-record