# How to get heroku websites IP Addresss?

Tags: api, rest, networking

I will integrate a rest api for my website. Integrator company wants an IP address for restrictions. I will send my computer ip for development and website (provider: heroku) ip for production. But i cant figure how the obtain these informations. Can anybody help or send an documentation about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku [does not provide a static IP](https://help.heroku.com/4WADH6LX/can-you-provide-me-with-the-ip-address-for-my-application).

Yet, here are 3 ways to make it work :

1. Give the domain address instead of an IP address to the integrator.

As Heroku is using volatile IP addresses, This is the best way.

2. Use an Add-on, [Fixie](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/fixie) or [Guru301](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/guru301) seems to do exactly that
3. not recommended : [Add a DNS A-record](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains) You can hard code your IP but it [doesn't look stable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32996579/5391965)